# Troubleshooting ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() or Class.getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, dynamic, file-io, classloader

I work on an application where the war has a directory structure like the following:

```
ear/war/modules/configuration/gsrc/<java packages start here>
```

However, I want to dynamically read a file that lives here:

```
/ear/war/modules/configuration/some/other/dir/somefile.csv
```

I have tried many permutations of the normal ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream() and Class.getResourceAsStream() to try to get a handle to that resource all of which come up with null such as:

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/modules/configuration/some/other/dir/somefile.csv")
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/configuration/some/other/dir/somefile.csv")
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("/some/other/dir/somefile.csv")
Class.getResourceAsStream("../some/other/dir/somefile.csv")
Class.getResourceAsStream("../../some/other/dir/somefile.csv")
Class.getResourceAsStream("../../../some/other/dir/somefile.csv")
```

My assumption is I'm using a classloader who's root scope is the gsrc directory where the code lives. What is the appropriate way to troubleshoot this?

For instance I was hoping I could print out something like ClassLoader.rootDirectory() to figure out what the root directory of the classloader is. Then I could print out the root dir of this classloader and it's parent(s), etc.

The runtime is jetty locally, but websphere in all other regions.

Comment: what server is being used (Tomcat, Websphere, etc ..)?

Comment: locally jetty. in dev,test,stage,prod websphere

Comment: We don't know how your WAR is assembled from this structure. Unzip your WAR file. If the CSV file is not under `WEB-INF/classes` or in an archive in `WEB-INF/lib` then it is likely not visible to any `ClassLoader`. If it is bundled elsewhere in the WAR then you will be able to access the file via the `ServletContext`.

Comment: My mistake, you're correct. This file is not on the classpath and hence is not available to the classloader. I assume that means the only way I could load the resource would be something roundabout like calling a webservice which would have a hook to the servlet context? What is the *best* way to access a file not on the classpath from java code.

Answer (score 0):

My Eclipse project has the following structure:

C:\workspace\ProjectName\src\com\my\package\resources\myfile.properties

So, to actually load this file I'm doing this:

```
getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/my/package/resources/myfile.properties")
```

I hope this example can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Either put the file in WEB-INF and access it from a servlet using

```
getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/somefile.csv");
```

or place it anywhere on the filesystem and access it either with the Java File API or Apache [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).